# Access logs from console.log() in Node.js vm module

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine

In [node.js vm module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), i can execute some javascript in another node.js process. What i want to achieve is being able to catch logs performed in the script runned by the vm.

For example i want to catch the "foobar" log:

```
var vm = require('vm')

vm.runInThisContext('console.log("foobar");', 'myfile.vm');

// how can i get the "foobar" log?
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The answer below works well, although there's a shorter version:

```
function captureStdout(callback) {
    var output = '', old_write = process.stdout.write

    // start capture
    process.stdout.write = function(str, encoding, fd) {
        output += str
    }

    callback()

    // end capture
    process.stdout.write = old_write

    return output
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just wrap console.log directly:

```
function hook_consolelog(callback) {
    var old_log = console.log;

    console.log = (function(write) {
        return function() {
            write.apply(console, arguments)
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    })(console.log)

    return function() {
        console.log = old_log;
    }
}

var result;
var unhook = hook_consolelog(function(v) {
    result = v;
});

console.log('hello');
unhook();
console.log('goodbye');
console.log('the result is ', result);​
```

Since `console.log` simply calls `process.stdout`, another approach would be to capture the stdout events using a [bit of wrapper magic like this](https://gist.github.com/729616):

```
var util = require('util')

function hook_stdout(callback) {
    var old_write = process.stdout.write

    process.stdout.write = (function(write) {
        return function(string, encoding, fd) {
            write.apply(process.stdout, arguments)
            callback(string, encoding, fd)
        }
    })(process.stdout.write)

    return function() {
        process.stdout.write = old_write
    }
}

var unhook = hook_stdout(function(string, encoding, fd) {
    util.debug('stdout: ' + util.inspect(string))
    if( string == 'foobar' ) { unhook(); }
});
```

Comment: THe stdout seems the best solution as it keeps logs formatting, thanks

Comment: @Kato But why does console.log doesn't work in vm.runInThisContext

Comment: I don't remember the nuances of this 10 year old problem. I imagine it had to do with console.log not working well with `.apply(...)`. I'd hope that a problem like this would have been solved during the 10 years since I posted this.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's better so just forward the current console to the newly created context object:

```js
let contextObj = {
    console: console
};
```

Comment: Even more simpler than mine, haha, I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Comment: I'd sure hope this works by now   I can't recall why it wasn't an option in the prior decade.

Answer (score 3):

I found another, IMHO simpler solution: we just need to overwrite the `console.log()` function inside the VM context to use the function from the outer context.

```js
import { Script, createContext } from 'vm';

let contextObj = {
    console: {
        log: (...args) => {
            console.log(...args);
        }
    }
};

const vmContext = createContext(contextObj);
const script = new Script("console.log('hello from the other side');");
script.runInContext(vmContext);
```

Hope it helps anyone looking for a stupidly simple solution!